# How to retrieve datatables input from feature file in step definition

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

**FeatureFile**

```
Feature: Shopper can add an item to their Grocery List
@kk
Scenario: Mutate multiple User Skills at the same time
Given I fill the customer details
| name | department |
| john | retail |
| mary | sales |
| ed | science |
```

**StepDefinition File**

```
Given(/^I fill the customer details$/, function (data) {
console.log("data----"+data)
console.log('table data: ', data.hashes());
done();
});
```

how can i get the data tables data in step definition
the step definition is written in **javascript**
 Cucumber-webdriverio

Comment: You will want to keep in mind, when passing a table in a cucumber step like this, the first column will be your key and the second column is data. So in this case, the keys passed in the table will be `name`, `john`, `mary`, and `ed`.

Comment: please suggest a step definition for the resolution
please suggest a step definition in javascript.....
i have get various resolution in java but my code require js.....

Comment: Try to use the examples here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable You can change to a list of map and then call the data you want